# How do i set working directory in sql developer in code

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using sql developer.

I want to run some scripts.
I don't want to have to include the folder name in the call to each script.

But I also want to use a variable to include the directory to look in (the working directory).

I can do this but i am having trouble with folder names with spaces (this is in windows).

Can anyone help me work out how to do this without having to rename my folder to remove spaces?

```
define dir="c:\Users\xx\Google Drive\Analytics\Recruitment\NSL\2. Data Understanding\Code"

@&dir\cb_nsl_impairments.sql;
```

Returns error

```
SP2-0310: Unable to open file: "c:\Users\xx\Google.sql"
```

Answer (score 3):

Oops. Solved it.

Just needed double quotes around the script call:

```
@"&dir\cb_nsl_impairments.sql"
```